# Compile-time "opposite" of std::less?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Apologies in advance. I'm having a bit of difficulty finding the right phrasing for this question...

As an exercise, I'm working on a fixed-size priority queue that throws away objects greater than the max (for a queue finding the X smallest object) and throws away objects less than min (for queue holding the largest X objects). The question is whether there is way of arriving at the logical "opposite" of the comparator at compile-time.

See commented line in the code below:

```
template <
    typename T, 
    typename Container = std::vector<T>, 
    typename Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>>
class fixed_size_priority_queue : public std::priority_queue<T, Container, Compare>
{
    typename Container::size_type maxSize;
    using base = std::priority_queue<T, Container, Compare>;

  public:
    fixed_size_priority_queue(std::size_t size) : base(), maxSize(size)
    {
        base::c.reserve(size);
    }
    void push(T value)
    {
        if (base::size() < maxSize)
        {
            base::push(value);
        }
        // is there some way of arriving at compile-time opposite of 'comp'?
        else if (!base::comp(base::top(), value))
        {
            while (base::size() >= maxSize)
            {
                base::pop();
            }
            base::push(value);
        }
    }
};

void test_fixedPriQueue()
{

    using smallestInts = fixed_size_priority_queue<int>;
    smallestInts fq(4);
    fq.push(5);
    fq.push(3);
    fq.push(5);
    fq.push(5);
    fq.push(7);
    fq.push(11);
    fq.push(1);
    fq.push(2);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    test_fixedPriQueue();
    return 0;
}
```

I've simply used the not (!) operator to get the job done, but would this incur an, albeit very small, runtime cost? Is there a way to arrive at `std::greater_equal` when my class uses `Compare = std::less`?

I was hoping to use something like `std::not<Compare>` which would resolve to `std::greater_equal` when the `Compare` template parameter is `std::less`. Does that make sense?

** edit **

Trying the suggestion from sergeyA yielded what I was looking for:

```
template<typename T, typename Comparison>
struct logical_opposite
{
    using op = void;
};

template <typename T>
struct logical_opposite<T, std::less<T>>
{
    using op = std::greater_equal<T>;
};

template <typename T>
struct logical_opposite<T, std::greater<T>>
{
    using op = std::less_equal<T>;
};
```

Then in the class derived from priority_queue, instantiate the logical opposite function object and use it when pushing into the queue:

```
//...
typename logical_opposite<T, Compare>::op not_comp;

public:
fixed_size_priority_queue(std::size_t size) : base(), maxSize(size), not_comp()
//....
```

There is a logical relationship between the comparison functor types and I was hoping that relationship was expressed in the STL.

Comment: [`std::not1(base::comp)`?](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not1)

Comment: Even if there would be some miniscule overhead (with optimizations there could be none), I'm not seeing how you can get `greater_equal` from `less` without a `!`. This seems like a textbook premature optimization, to be honest.

Comment: @YSC I did see this, but noticed it is deprecated and soon to be obsolete.

Comment: And for a good reason: it's been made obsolete since lambdas.

Comment: You can create a templatized trait, which would select the opposite version based on the template argument, and specify each conversion. Tedious, and likely no quantifiable performance benefit.

Comment: @YSC: isn't `not_fn` a replacement for it?

Comment: @geza And they are all evil from the perspective of the question.

Comment: @PasserBy: Evil? why?

Comment: @geza _"I've simply used the not (!) operator to get the job done, but would this incur an, albeit very small, runtime cost?"_

Comment: @PasserBy: ah, ok :) I think it's very rarely matters. I mean, most of the time, code won't be supoptimal because of it. Anyways, I've just asked about `not_fn`, because as it seems, it is not deprecated without a replacement.

Comment: @veefu: I would not worry about the performance. If you use LTO, it's almost certain that you don't get any performance degradation. If you don't use LTO, then in very rare circumstances, you can get a very small hit.

Comment: Why is everyone so concerned about performance? That really wasn't my question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no observable difference between `!<` and `>=` on primitive types, so your fear of a runtime cost is ungrounded.

C++ is not assembly.  It describes the behaviour of an abstract machine.  Compilers map this to assembly, and operations that have no observable difference can be implemented identically in assembly.

While it takes some experience to learn what is "observable" in C++, the general rule is write clean code that avoids allocations when reasonable, keep da contiguous and keep O-notation speed sane, then test programs for performance problems before you worry about other issues.

`!<` vs `>=` is not one of the "avoid premature pessimisation" issues, so you should ignore it unless you find the code when profiling.

Comment: Perhaps mentioning a runtime cost at all has gotten away from what I really mean to ask. The question is whether there is a built-in way to deduce at that `not (std::less)` is more simply expressed as `std::greater_equal` at compile time.

Comment: "operations that have no observable difference can be implemented identically in assembly". It is theoretically possible, but there are a lot of occasions where the compiler doesn't do it. But you're right on the part that the extra negation usually doesn't cost anything, as it can be fused into some other operation.

Comment: @veefu the comparator is passed in, so definitely not?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I've added to the question a bit, which maybe clarifies the question, to some degree. You mention "observable differences on *primative* types". Why the qualified answer? What happens with more complicated user-defined types in such cases?